# Unable to vibrate my android using kivy app and buildozer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

My task is to make my android device vibrate using kivy and buildozer. But everytime I include the ***plyer*** module in my `main.py`, it throws an error. This error is thrown when I add the plyer module in my **main.py** code.

```
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Error while running "/home/monojit/pyPrac/kivy/new/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 -OO -m compileall -b -f /home/monojit/pyPrac/kivy/new/.buildozer/android/app"
This probably means one of your Python files has a syntax error, see logs above
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3.6 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name Mycalc --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/monojit/pyPrac/kivy/new/.buildozer/android/app --permission VIBRATE --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/monojit/pyPrac/kivy/new/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/monojit'
#     SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/home/monojit/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     VTE_VERSION = '4205'
#     QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON = '1'
#     WINDOWID = '69206026'
#     UPSTART_SESSION = 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1505'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL = ''
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module'
#     USER = 'monojit'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/monojit:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1734,unix/monojit:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1734'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/monojit/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/monojit/anaconda3/bin:/home/monojit/bin:/home/monojit/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/snap/bin'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'appmenu-qt5'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     JOB = 'dbus'
#     PWD = '/home/monojit/pyPrac/kivy/new'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_PID = ''
#     LANG = 'en_IN'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE = 'ubuntu'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SESSIONTYPE = 'gnome-session'
#     GTK2_MODULES = 'overlay-scrollbar'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     HOME = '/home/monojit'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LOGNAME = 'monojit'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-KSt1VHdtUJ'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     INSTANCE = ''
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/monojit/.Xauthority'
#     _ = '/home/monojit/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/monojit/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/monojit/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/monojit/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

What kind of error is it? Is it related to android vibrate permission? I have given permission in the **buildozer.spec** file.

Comment: send the whole log

Comment: > Error while running "/home/monojit/pyPrac/kivy/new/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 -OO -m compileall -b -f /home/monojit/pyPrac/kivy/new/.buildozer/android/app"
 This probably means one of your Python files has a syntax error, see logs above